# AutoFill excel columns

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am creating Excel from my application and I want to get an Excel file with autofit column size.

After filling the table in the workbook, I set the columns using this method:

```
public void AutoFitColumns(Sheet sheet)
{
    //get all cells in sheet
    IEnumerable<Cell> cells = GetCells(sheet);
    //find max column number
    int maxColumnIndex = cells.Select(a => GetColumnIndex(a.CellReference))
        .Where(a => a.HasValue)
        .Select(a => a.Value)
        .Distinct()
        .Max();

    Worksheet worksheet = GetWorkSheetPart(sheet).Worksheet;
    // Check if the column collection exists
    Columns cs = worksheet.Elements<Columns>().FirstOrDefault();

    if (cs == null)
    {
        // If Columns appended to worksheet after sheetdata Excel will throw an error.
        SheetData sd = worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (sd != null)
            cs = worksheet.InsertBefore(new Columns(), sd);
        else
        {
            cs = new Columns();
            worksheet.Append(cs);
        }
    }

    Column c = new Column
    {
        Min = (uint)1,
        Max = (uint)maxColumnIndex,
        Width = 100D,
        CustomWidth = true,
        BestFit = true
    };
    cs.Append(c);
}
```

For some reason I don't see the properta of the BestFit column. I found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/cc802410(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN where it is described:

> Flag indicating if the specified column (s) is set to 'best fit'.
>   'Best fit' is set to true under the following conditions: The column
>   width has never been manually set by the user, AND The column width is
>   not the default width 'Best fit' means that when numbers are typed
>   into a cell contained in a 'best fit' column, the column width should
>   automatically resize to display the number. [Note: In best fit cases,
>   column width must not be made smaller, only larger. end note]

So I tried several ways to apply the automatic column width, as described in the document and the "Trial / Error" method

Does anyone have any idea why this doesn't work?

My steps are as follows:

- Create styles and formats used in Excel
- Create a table with data (individual values in the correct format) for each cell
- I want to create columns and compare the table to automatic column width according to content

Comment: sounds like bestfit is a method which returns a boolean, ie. it is not a settable propety

Comment: it is settable property. In final XML is visible as 1 value

Comment: I recommend you create a simple Excel file, save it. Then set the kind of column width you want. Save this to a different name and close. Open the first file in the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool, then use the Compare feature to compare it to the second file. This will show you both the difference in the XML and the code to generate the second file from the first. You should find the code for setting the column width fairly simply...

Comment: MS Excel application sets up after auto-fit specific column width value. But Open XML SDK setup xml attribute BestFit to "1"